# Why Oracle database requires to provide at least single partition when creating partition by interval

Tags: database, oracle, partitioning, database-partitioning

I wonder why Oracle Databases require that at least single partition is defined when creating `PARTITION BY RANGE INTERVAL`

This is correct:

`CREATE TABLE FOO (
  bar VARCHAR2(10),
  creation_date timestamp(6) not null
)
PARTITION BY RANGE (creation_date) INTERVAL (NUMTODSINTERVAL(1,'DAY')) (
  PARTITION part_01 values LESS THAN (TO_DATE('01-03-2018','DD-MM-YYYY'))
)`

This however not:

`CREATE TABLE FOO (
  bar VARCHAR2(10),
  creation_date timestamp(6) not null
)
PARTITION BY RANGE (creation_date) INTERVAL (NUMTODSINTERVAL(1,'DAY'))`

I would expect that the first partition would be required in some migration case but not when creating a new table.

Oracle documentation about that:

> The INTERVAL clause of the CREATE TABLE statement establishes interval partitioning for the table. You must specify at least one range partition using the PARTITION clause.
>   https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25523/part_admin001.htm#BAJHFFBE

Comment: Voted to move to [dba.se]

Comment: This may halp you to get that rationale: if you say *I need one week holiday*; you very soon gets the response such as: *Starting from which date?*

Comment: It is not clear what you expect. If you partition your table, whenever (now or in the future) you add data to the table, it has to go to a partition. Perhaps you are asking "why isn't the entire table in a single partition by default, if I don't say otherwise". That's fine, but the partition MUST have a name so it can be referred to. Where are you providing that name?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Without default interval Oracle does not know where to start the interval. For daily partition it is not so obvious but imagine you have one partition per week, i.e. 7 days.

Shall it be Monday-Monday or Sunday-Sunday or something else?

What does an interval of "1 DAY" mean? From 00:00:00 - 23:59:59 (as implicitly given in your example) or something else, for example 12:00:00 - 11:59:59 (which would be `PARTITION part_01 values LESS THAN (TO_DATE('01-03-2018 12:00','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI'))`)